# MySQL Workbench save resized columns

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is it possible to have the columns resized automagically in MySQL Workbench 6.1 (or any version)? Below you'll see the first column `time_captured` is always truncated, and I need to resize it after each query in order to see the full value:

[image: sample output]

One goofy way I've sidestepped the problem is to do this

```
select date(time_captured), time(time_captured), object_id, group_size from MY_TABLE;
```

But it's kind of awkward.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation and there are plans to improve handling of column autosizing and persistence in a better way than what we have now. This also means, there's nothing in the current release that you can use.